# Unable to install Github-Pages with gem?

Tags: ruby, rvm, gem, jekyll

I've been trying to install github-pages using gem.
I have Ruby v. 2.1.2:

```
✦ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
```

I installed Ruby using RVM and I've set 2.1.2 as my default version to use. Somehow, I'm still getting this error message:

```
✦ sudo gem install github-pages
    ERROR:  Error installing github-pages:
    jekyll requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

*Moved OP'solution left in the question into a Community Wiki Answer*

> My end goal was to install Jekyll.  Github-pages was not cooperating. 
>   Instead, I installed Jekyll directly with:
>
> ```
> gem install jekyll
> ```
>
> https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/